# flex slider thumbs view not showing correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexslider

I have a slider from flex slider. With 4 images it works very well but when used with more than 5 images, thumbs view is not shown correctly. How can I fix this? [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTJPQ.png).

Comment: I think it would be better if you use the Thumbnail Slider, not the Thumbnail Navigation for it seems that TN Navigation only allows 4 images per row. Also, your images have different proportions. Try setting them as background-images for a fixed width/height element & that should do it.

Comment: Post your code please. We can't help you with code unless we see your source code. We can only make assumptions.

Comment: i posted my code as answer.please check that

Answer (score 0):

here my code

```
<div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <?php
      $pre_ads_images=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE pid=".$ad_out['id']);
      while($ad_images=$pre_ads_images->fetch_assoc()){
        echo'
          <li data-thumb="'.$base_dir.'/uploads/post/'.$ad_images['uid'].'/'.$ad_images['name'].'">
            <img src="'.$base_dir.'/uploads/post/'.$ad_images['uid'].'/'.$ad_images['name'].'" alt="'.$ad_out['title'].' For Sale In '.$city_y['name'].'"/>
          </li>';
        }
   ?>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>$('.flexslider').flexslider({animation: "slide",controlNav: "thumbnails"});</script>
```

Comment: Your problem isn't really the PHP bit but rather the CSS applied on your HTML structure. To be more specific: the thumbnails for 5+ images don't show up properly for 3 reasons: CSS code, non-fixed thumbnail size (also part of CSS code) and perhaps some bit of your HTML structure.

Comment: For a start, make sure your thumbnail images are of equal dimensions. This will make sure you don't get abnormal thumbnails at the bottom that will break the layout.

Comment: yes best idea is set maximum amount of thumb view image.thanks all for supporting me